# PhantomJS WebDriver timeout (access via Selenium Grid)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid

I need to set (descrease) PhantomJS timeout: 300000 (300sec) -> 30000 (30sec)

I have Selenium Grid with attached PhantomJS as WebDriver.
PhantoimJS exec command:

```
phantomjs --config=phantomjs.json --webdriver=6661  --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4440
```

Content of phantomjs.json (i add random values for test):

```
{
    "resourceTimeout": 123456,
    "timeout": 345678,
    "wait": 234567    
}
```

But in Selenium grid shows **timeout: 300000**

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPwBQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Here is config for selenium grid (hub.json):

```
{
  "host": null,
  "port": 4440,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 60000,
  "browserTimeout": 60000,
  "maxSession": 25,
  "maxInstances": 25,
  "jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

So i need to rub selenium with params:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
```

The profit!